# Multiple equally sized plots in an RMarkdown document

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I would like to align **the area** of several plots, each of them created by separate chunks in an RMarkdown document (preferably .html) "nicely". My problem: Because of the different lengths of the y-axis texts. The plotted **area** doesn't overlap perfectly (A pity because my actual x-axis is months).

Setting the `fig.width=` and `out.width=` don't help here as they consider the axis text lengths.

Dummy Data chunk:

```r
require(ggplot2)

df = expand.grid(y = LETTERS,
                 x = paste0('A', 1:10),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set.seed(42)
df$fill = rnorm(nrow(df))
df2 = df
df2$y = unlist(lapply(lapply(df2$y, function(x) rep(x, 10)), paste0, collapse = ''))
```

Plot-Chunk1:

```r
gg1 = ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()
gg1
```

Plot-Chunk2:

```r
gg2 = ggplot(df2, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()
gg2
```

The plots in the RMarkdown document should look like that (red lines highlight the desired alignment):

[image]

I achieved this with the patchwork package. However, like this I can only use one chunk and not multiple.

Patchwork-Plot-Chunk:

```r
require(patchwork)

gg1 / gg2 +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
```

Comment: Knit to html or pdf?

Comment: .html I'll update the question.

Comment: Mr. Andy was faster than I :)

Comment: a bit of copypasta from my own scripts lol. And I am still hoping that someone comes with a more 'correct' way of doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **patchwork** package also includes the function `align_patches()` which works similar to `cowplot::align_plots()`.

```r
gg_l = patchwork::align_patches(gg1,
                                gg2)
```

Plot-Chunk1:

```r
gg_l[[1]]
```

Plot-Chunk2:

```r
gg_l[[2]]
```

*Data from question.*

Answer (score 1):

## Edited (tidier?) solution: `cowplot::align_plots`

Having a bit of a play around with `cowplot::align_plots`, it would be possible to set a standard panel width to use across all graphs. But to do this across chunks when you're constructing each graph 'blind' to the forthcoming ones, you could create a 'template' plot with labels as wide as needed (`gg_set` below). Each subsequent graph would then adopt the sizing of this unused plot:

```r
require(ggplot2)

df  <-  expand.grid(y = LETTERS,
                    x = paste0('A', 1:10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set.seed(42)
df$fill = rnorm(nrow(df))

df2  <-  df
df2$y  <-
  unlist(lapply(lapply(df2$y, function(x)
    rep(x, 5)), paste0, collapse = ''))


# df for setting max size needed - might need experimented with
dfset  <-  df
dfset$y  <-
  unlist(lapply(lapply(df$y, function(x)
    rep(x, 10)), paste0, collapse = ''))


# 'template' plot
gg_set <-  ggplot(dfset, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()


require(cowplot)

# Chunk 1
gg1  <-  ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()

ggs <- align_plots(gg_set, gg1, align = "v")

# Only extracting relevant graph.
ggdraw(ggs[[2]])
```

[image]

```r
# Chunk 2
gg2  <-  ggplot(df2, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()

ggs <- align_plots(gg_set, gg2, align = "v")

ggdraw(ggs[[2]])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Untidy former solution

I've previously used an admittedly messy solution, which really just involves padding all labels with blank rows above and below to greater than the max length:

```r
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df  <-  expand.grid(y = LETTERS,
                    x = paste0('A', 1:10),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set.seed(42)
df$fill = rnorm(nrow(df))
df2  <-  df
df2$y  <-
  unlist(lapply(lapply(df2$y, function(x)
    rep(x, 10)), paste0, collapse = ''))


df$y <-
  paste0(paste0(rep(" ", 40), collapse = ""), "\n", df$y, "\n", paste0(rep(" ", 40)))
df2$y <-
  paste0(paste0(rep(" ", 40), collapse = ""), "\n", df2$y, "\n", paste0(rep(" ", 40)))

gg1  <-  ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()
gg1
```

[image]

```r
gg2 <-  ggplot(df2, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = fill)) +
  geom_tile()
gg2
```

[image]

I would hope their is a more formal solution which allows a static panel sizing, and I look forward to hearing other answers. But had used this as a quick fix!

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I asked because I wanted to avoid this approach, but hey, if that's all we got, then ok.

Comment: I have another idea!!! coming shortly in edits...

Comment: That's nice! Thanks for pointing me to `cowplot::align_plots(..., align = "v")`